# Defining an interface that implements comparable

Tags: java, interface, comparable

I'm trying to define an interface such that all implementing classes must be Comparable to themselves and their subclasses.

For example, consider:

```
public interface Rating implements Comparable<Rating> {}
```

This means that implementing classes must be Comparable to all Ratings:

```
public class A implements Rating {
    public int compareTo(Rating r) {return 0;}
}
```

I'd like to loosen that requirement so that I can define a class like:

```
public class A implements Rating {
    public int compareTo(A a) {return 0;}
}
```

Comment: An `interface` extends another `interface` do not implement.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do again?

Comment: Can't be done. Fundamentally, you would need to write a type on Rating that says "the type of the class actually implementing this interface", and there just isn't a way to do that in Java. I think this is a case of what's known as a "dependent type"; these exist only in a few research languages, and haven't been fully worked out yet.

Comment: Tom has answered my question. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

I expect you're trying to get at something like this:

```
public class Rating implements Comparable<? extends Rating> {
   ...
}
```

or maybe (although I'm not sure you can do this):

```
public interface Rating extends Comparable<? extends Rating> {
   ...
}
```

See [this page at Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) for more information on bounded wildcards.

Answer (score -1):

1. I imagine you probably want your "compareTo()" to return something besides "0" ;)
2. You can use "instanceof" to see if an arbitrary object is some particular class (or a subclass)
3. I'm not sure overloading "compareTo()" is necessarily a good idea.  You might even want to make the input argument "Object o".

IMHO .. pSM

Comment: seems to me that you're answering the question before the question has been adequately defined yet. Edit: Not my down vote by the way.